# When remove someone from paid private repo, will they still be able to push code

Tags: mysql, git, amazon-web-services, github

i tried doing some research on this, but i wasnt able to find a solid answer.

The situation is, at our company we want to get rid of an employee, but he has a lot of access to our software. If we were to remove him from our paid private repo on github, will that deny them access to push any code?

We also use MySQL workbench, how would we deny him access to change stuff in the database, and AWS.

Any help would be great, not much into tech. Our main goal is to remove this person from company so they wouldnt cause harm to system in the future

Comment: Yes, if you remove his user from the repo, he will not be able to push to it or view it anymore. If you're unsure, you can try it out with another user and give them access again after you've tested it.

Comment: Either remove their User account on MySQL or if you all share an account (now you know why thats bad) you will have to change the password

Comment: im pretty sure we share an account..not 100% sure..when i type this in the mysql CL this appears: SELECT User,Host FROM mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------+
| User             | Host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| local            | %         |
| portal           | %         |
| mysql.infoschema | localhost |
| mysql.session    | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | localhost |
| root             | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+

Comment: and then we also have our company name ****.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com...how would re strict access from that too

Comment: It's quite troubling that your company doesn't have a process here and you are asking Stack Overflow. You should have a legal counsel. Some ideas: http://ina-inc.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Avoid_Being_Held_Hostage.pdf

Answer (score 0):

When you remove someone from a private git repo, they cannot push or pull from your repo anymore. The only thing they might still have are local copies of the repo of they forked or saved a copy on their machine

https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/removing-a-member-from-your-organization

> They will lose access to private forks of your organization's private
>   repositories, but may still have local copies. However, they cannot
>   sync local copies with your organization's repositories. Their private
>   forks can be restored if the user is reinstated as an organization
>   member within three months of being removed from the organization.
>   Ultimately, you are responsible for ensuring that people who have lost
>   access to a repository delete any confidential information or
>   intellectual property.